# Add npm start in mac shortcuts action

Tags: node.js, macos, macos-sierra, macos-shortcuts

There is a requirement to run a `npm start` comment using a Mac `shortcut action`

I added the commands to the `Run Shell Script` action.
[image]

But it throws the following error on run
[image]